# Is there an object-oriented alternative to the Front Controller Pattern?

Tags: oop, web, design-patterns

Okay, so i stumbled upon the [Front Controller Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/front-controller-design-pattern/), and as far as i know from web frameworks like [Spring Web (Java)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) or [Flask (Python)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/), they all embody this Design Pattern, leading to code such as (sample Spring Web):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SYSADMIN')")
@GetMapping(value = "/path/to/{id}/somewhere")
public void doIt(@PathVariable("id") String id)
{
    // ...
}

@PostMapping(value = "/path/to/{id}/somewhere")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SYSADMIN')")
public SomeDto doSomething(@PathVariable("id") String id)
{
    // ...
}

@GetMapping(value = "/api/agb/check")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SYSADMIN')")
public SomeDto doSomeotherthing()
{
    // ...
}

@GetMapping(value = "/api/agb")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SYSADMIN')")
public List<SomeDto> getAll()
{
    // ...
}
```

The "advantage" of this pattern is the centralized control flow, is said. But, isn´t it the case that object-oriented design is about distributing responsibilities and therefore getting rid of such centralized control flow?

Is there a more object-oriented design alternative to the front controller pattern when handling web requests?

Comment: BTW, GeeksForGeeks is not an authoritative source. It's a useful website, but it's primarily intended for brain-dumping for technical interviews - and there's plenty of bad and really outdated advice on there. It's like w3schools but for CS/SE...

Comment: "But, isn´t it the case that object-oriented design is about distributing responsibilities and therefore getting rid of such centralized control flow?" - no, that's not what I think/feel OOP is about at all (others may disagree, ofc). Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: "Is there a more object-oriented design alternative to the front controller pattern when handling web requests?" - why are you so-keen on being OOP? It's 2021 now, not 1995: OOP is going out off fashion for too many reasons.

Comment: I got the idea to get rid of centralized control from David Wests "Object Thinking" book. Dont want to Start the whole oop debate here, tbh.

Comment: I think you're running into "When your only tool is a hammer, every problem is a nail"-thinking: clearly you're familiar with OOP so you try to reason about every problem as an OOP design question, but you're not considering alternatives like FP or modern interpretations of OOP like immutability. Your book is from 2004 (according to Amazon) so it predates a lot of the major shifts in SE that have happened over the past 15 years, not to mention all of the major changes to OOP languages since then (e.g. Java generics in 2004, C++ concepts, etc). I strongly suggest you get a more modern book.

Comment: i am fully aware of all the points you are mentioning, of course there´re always more solutions for any given problem. but i am interested in solving this problem in an object-oriented way, using object-oriented design techniques. from my perspective, the front controller pattern embodies centralized control and is therefore a kind of "falling back" to procedural programming. i hoped someone either agrees with me and can propose a more object-oriented design, or disagrees with me and can show me how my thinking about the pattern itself is wrong.

Comment: I _get you_, but I think you're incorrect about thinking OOP has anything to do with "distributing responsibilities": while OOP does make it easy to partition code (into classes) following the business/domain model, that ability is not unique to OOP and it frequently causes problems due to OOP's limitations. Similarly, "Centralized control" is not a part of OOP either.

Comment: The view that an object is self-contained and responds to messages is valid. But you must then consider who dispatches the messages. In this case, the front controller dispatches HTTP requests (the messages) to the objects that know how to respond to them. In purist fashion you _could_ implement a mechanism to broadcast incoming messages, leaving each object to deal with them as per their design, but that implementation is inefficient. As the developer you already know which object responds to which message and so you can connect the dots. OO design doesn't always translate one-to-one to OOP.

Comment: i reconsidered the question, and i came to one conclusion: the front-controller pattern is not meant to be object-oriented, but instead it is derived from a more component-based programming paradigm. that is the reason my question initially doesn´t make that much sense, it´s like comparing apples and bananas.
i know this sounds really theoretical, but i try to fit possible ways to come to a clean design into my head. and there is a clear separation between object-oriented and component-based (although the latter stands on the shoulders of the former).

Comment: I agree 100% that the layered architecture exemplified by Spring MVC is _not_ object oriented. It is not even MVC, as compared to the original MVC architecture from Smalltalk, which is described in the GoF book. My experience has been that most developers assume they are doing OOP because they are using a certain language or a certain framework. In reality they are all doing procedural programming (separation of logic from data). Unfortunately, I do not know a top-to-bottom, OO solution for client/server (web) applications. Such a solution would be unrecognizable to most developers anyway.